# How can I plot candlestick charts with finplot and yfinance on Spyder 4+ IDE?

Tags: python, spyder, yfinance

I am a python newbie trying to learn plot some candlestick charts with yfinance on Spyder IDE. I am trying finplot, but the examples that you see on the web do not seem to work at all. Is this not supposed to work with Spyder? What am I missing?

First, install finplot and yfinance from the python console.

```
pip install finplot
pip install yfinance
```

Then in the spyder IDE, copy and paste the example code:

```
import finplot as fplt
import yfinance
df = yfinance.download('AAPL')
fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']])
fplt.show()
```

Result:

```
runfile('C:/Users/billgates/.spyder-py3/untitled8.py', wdir='C:/Users/billgates/.spyder-py3')
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\billgates\.spyder-py3\untitled8.py", line 4, in <module>
    fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']])

  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1304, in candlestick_ochl
    _set_datasrc(ax, datasrc)

  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1921, in _set_datasrc
    viewbox.datasrc.addcols(datasrc)

  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 284, in addcols
    self.df = pd.concat([df, newcols], axis=1)

  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 298, in concat
    return op.get_result()

  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 516, in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)

  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3171, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError(

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: there seens to be some space after AAPL

Comment: there is no extra space. I have also tried it with other symbols and they all give the same result.

Comment: Try `pip install -U ...` to get the newest version of each library.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to create plot. try this.

```
import finplot as fplt
import yfinance
df = yfinance.download('AAPL')
ax = fplt.create_plot()
fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']], ax=ax)
fplt.show()
```